# Count every third <span>

Tags: javascript

Website: https://bit . ly/1MHItEH

You see the red numbers? I want to count just the every third span to one sum. `x+x+x+x=Y`
How do i do that and can someone help me?
I think the solution is to count every third span but how?
Code example:

```html
<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'> 
   
  <tbody>
    <tr style='background: #fff;'>
      <td><span style='background-color: #5cb85c; border-radius: .25em; padding: .2em .6em .3em; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; font-size: 10pt; '>Online</i></span></td>      

      <td><span style='color: #fff; font-size: 10pt;'>79.98.30.225:27030</span></td>
      <td><span style='text-shadow: 0 0 10px #FF003C; color: #ff0041; font-size: 20pt;'>10</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='background: #fff;'>
      <td><span style='background-color: #5cb85c; border-radius: .25em; padding: .2em .6em .3em; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; font-size: 10pt; '>Online</i></span></td>      

      <td><span style='color: #fff; font-size: 10pt;'>45.125.66.156:27015</span></td>
      <td><span style='text-shadow: 0 0 10px #FF003C; color: #ff0041; font-size: 20pt;'>0</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='background: #fff;'>
      <td><span style='background-color: #5cb85c; border-radius: .25em; padding: .2em .6em .3em; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; font-size: 10pt; '>Online</i></span></td>      

      <td><span style='color: #fff; font-size: 10pt;'>185.80.129.199:27015</span></td>
      <td><span style='text-shadow: 0 0 10px #FF003C; color: #ff0041; font-size: 20pt;'>0</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You could give them a class and then use `getElementsByClassName().length`. btw, your html is invalid - center tag is obsolete and should not be used, and it cannot be a direct child of the table

Comment: Or count everything and divide by 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `querySelectorAll('tr td:nth-child(3) span')` like:

```js
var totalCount = 0;
document.querySelectorAll('tr td:nth-child(3) span').forEach(function(s){
  totalCount += parseInt(s.textContent);
});

console.log(totalCount);
```

```html
<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'> 

<center><iframe src="X" width="640" style="max-height:35px;" height="35" scrolling="auto" frameBorder="0"></iframe></center>

  <tbody>
    <tr style='background: #fff;'>
      <td><span style='background-color: #5cb85c; border-radius: .25em; padding: .2em .6em .3em; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; font-size: 10pt; '>Online</i></span></td>      

      <td><span style='color: #fff; font-size: 10pt;'>79.98.30.225:27030</span></td>
      <td><span style='text-shadow: 0 0 10px #FF003C; color: #ff0041; font-size: 20pt;'>10</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='background: #fff;'>
      <td><span style='background-color: #5cb85c; border-radius: .25em; padding: .2em .6em .3em; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; font-size: 10pt; '>Online</i></span></td>      

      <td><span style='color: #fff; font-size: 10pt;'>45.125.66.156:27015</span></td>
      <td><span style='text-shadow: 0 0 10px #FF003C; color: #ff0041; font-size: 20pt;'>0</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='background: #fff;'>
      <td><span style='background-color: #5cb85c; border-radius: .25em; padding: .2em .6em .3em; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; font-size: 10pt; '>Online</i></span></td>      

      <td><span style='color: #fff; font-size: 10pt;'>185.80.129.199:27015</span></td>
      <td><span style='text-shadow: 0 0 10px #FF003C; color: #ff0041; font-size: 20pt;'>0</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Instead of console.log(totalCount); how do i just print it? How can i explain it just print it out on a page instead of console.

Comment: Where do you want to to print? inside an element?

Comment: Well to a separate .txt .html or .php would be perfect.

Comment: Storing that in another separate file is another different task to achieve. Why don't you create a `div` right after the table then place that count in that `div`

Comment: As you see on my web i need to put the count in ''Players right now'' so its much easier to just make script make a separate .txt .html or .php so i just can iframe the total count.